# How to parse CLOB cloumn by DB2 select statement itself?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with CLOB column (text separated by new line or comma).
E.g. CLOBCOLUM = "name1, name2, name3..."
I can read it and parse by Java (row by row)

```
String rowName;
Clob clob = rs.getClob("CLOBCOLUM ");
BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(clob.getCharacterStream());

while ((rowName = bufferRead.readLine()) != null) {
   ..............
```

But I want to parse it by DB2 itself. I.e. get CLOB column data and insert it into another table row by row. Something like that:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (ID, COLUMN1) VALUES (SELECT ID, CLOBCOLUM???? FROM TABLE2)
```

Or MERGE statement is even better.
So table TABLE1 would look like this:

```
ID   COLUMN1
1    name1
1    name2
1    name3
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Start with the SELECT part alone. Can you write that one, you're almost done.

Comment: so how do I SELECT to extract CLOB as an ARRAY?

Comment: Probably done in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a recursive query:

```
WITH t(i,v,c) AS 
(
SELECT id,'',clobcolum FROM TABLE2
UNION ALL
SELECT i,SUBSTR(c,1,POSSTR(c,',')-1),SUBSTR(c,POSSTR(c,',')+1) FROM t WHERE POSSTR(c,',') > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT i,c,'' FROM t WHERE c>'' AND POSSTR(c,',') = 0
)
SELECT i,v FROM t WHERE v > ''
```